# matplotlib: ax.tick_params for the Z axis in 3D plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

One can use

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=10)
```

to set the font size of the tick labels on the X axis.

However, when I try to do the same for the Z axis

```
ax.tick_params(axis='z', labelsize=10)
```

but get this error:

```
ValueError: 'z' is not a valid value for axis; supported values are 'x', 'y', 'both'
```

This seems quite strange to me, as one does need to set these properties for the Z axis.

Comment: The docs for [mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D. tick_params](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.tick_params) states that "Also, the axis parameter also accepts a value of 'z', which would mean to apply to only the z-axis." are you sure you have the correct `ax` variable?

Comment: @HenryEcker Thank you! Indeed, I was looking at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params, which is about the 2D "Axes" object. Thanks again for pointing this out!